# Lead Generation Forms & Privacy Policy

Tags: email, spam, marketing, privacy-policy

I have a lead form in my website (A website about High-End Fashion) in which visitors can contact a sales representative about **product A**. There is no opt-in checkbox, just a couple of text fields (phone number, e-mail etc...) and I received several thousands of submissions from customers in the UK. The form's purpose is to schedule an appointment.

I want to send these leads a marketing mail of **product B**. It's a different product from the same brand and I know it's relevant to those leads - But, it's a completely different product category.

Currently, I do not have a privacy policy in my website.

1. Can I legally send such e-mails?
2. What kind of privacy policy do I need in my website for this to be legal?

Comment: You should also study the T&C's of which ever service you use to send the marketing emails from. If you sent me one of these emails I would inspect the email headers and file an abuse report. I get accounts banned regularly and it's better for you to disclose your intentions in advance and let people opt in if they're still interested - this group is far more likely to convert to a sale too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

across the EU there is a concept that allows you to send emails to a list without their permission, but *that's still based on prior permission*.

It's known as 'soft opt-in'. It applies if the following conditions are met;

- where you've obtained a person's details in the course of a sale or negotiations for a sale of a product or service;
- where the messages are only marketing similar products or services; and
- where the person is given a simple opportunity to refuse marketing when their details are collected, and if they don't opt out at this point, are given a simple way to do so in future messages.

Though you seem to have two problems imo: you don't actually have their consent email them (which is a different purpose), nor have you ever shown them a privacy notice. Therefore theoretically you'd need to create new consent.

I think you might be interested in reading these two guides by the UK authority, the ICO:

- [Direct Marketing Checklist](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/documents/1551/direct-marketing-checklist.pdf)
- [Direct Marketing](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/documents/1555/direct-marketing-guidance.pdf)

which will go into detail about the requirements for successfully navigating the waters of compliance.

Regarding your second question - what **kind of privacy policy you need** - that privacy policy will need to follow the minimum standards of EU/UK law and case law and include the data processing practices, along with the information about direct marketing being done by you.

P.S. I've written a bit about the [topic on my company blog here](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-email-newsletter/), which might also give you some desired insights.

Answer (score 1):

You are collecting personal data from users to send them promotional emails.

You can send those emails as long as you have a proper disclosure to users that they may receive promotional emails and you have a Privacy Policy where you disclose what kind of personal data you collect, what are you going to do with that data and how users can opt-out from your emails.

In summary:

- Depending on your jurisdiction, read about CAN-SPAM in the USA, the new GDPR in the EU and the DPA in the UK.
- Research how to draft a more prominent disclosure of your data collection in your lead generation forms. Clickwrap method (without or without the ‘I agree’ checkbox) is a good start.
- Draft a Privacy Policy where you disclose:

  - What information you collect from users.
  - What will you do with the collected personal information.
  - With whom you share the collected personal information, i.e. with third-parties
  - How users can unsubscribe from your promotional emails.
- Place links to your Privacy Policy on your lead generation page
- Place unsubscribe links in your emails